# Broken hair mirroring

Tags: hair, mirror, particle-edit-mode

I have a mesh that has Mirror and Subdivision modifiers (in that order) applied to it. I'm trying to add symmetrical fur/hair to it.

It looks like this:
[image: model]

Why, when there are no particles on the right, is there hair on the right?

Additionally, if I select the particles and mirror them, the mirrored particles are shifted some distance to the right (+x) rather than being mirrored across the origin.

How can I fix these problems *without* applying the other modifiers?

(I am using Blender 3.3.6.)

[image]